# Programación Paralela Python

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando un programa que simula un elevador, este sube o baja entre 5 pisos. El elevador tiene un límite de 5 personas que pueden estar en este al mismo tiempo.

Parte del código es el siguiente:

```
max_pasajeros = 10 #Total de personas que existen 
espacios = 5
pisoActual = 0
listaDestino = []
listaOrigen = []
multiplex = threading.Semaphore(5) # 5 espacios en el ascensor
mutex = threading.Semaphore(1) 
torniquete = threading.Semaphore(1)
pisoActual = 0
pisoOrigen = 0
upOrDown = 0

def ascensor():
    global pisoActual
    global listaOrigen
    global listaDestino
    global upOrDown

    while True:
        if listaDestino != []:
            print("Ascensor en el piso: ", pisoActual, 'esperando\n')
        else:
            while listaDestino != []:
                time.sleep(3)
                print("Ascensor en el piso: ", pisoActual)

                if upOrDown == 0:    
                    subirPersona()
                else:
                    bajarPersona()

def pasajero(id):
    global pisoActual
    global listaDestino
    global listaOrigen

    while True:
        torniquete.acquire()
        torniquete.release()

        multiplex.acquire()
        mutex.acquire()

        pisoOrigen = random.randrange(1, 5)
        pisoDestino = random.randrange(1, 5)

        while pisoOrigen == pisoDestino:
            pisoDestino = random.randrange(1, 5)
        
        listaOrigen.append(pisoOrigen)
        listaDestino.append(pisoDestino)
        print("Origen: ", listaOrigen)
        print("Destino: ", listaDestino)
        
        print("Pasajero", id, "del piso", pisoOrigen, "al", pisoDestino, "\n")
    
        while pisoActual != listaOrigen[0]:
            time.sleep(5)
        print("Pasajero", id, "subiendo al ascensor. Piso:", pisoActual)
        listaOrigen.pop(0)
    
        while pisoActual != listaDestino[0]:
            time.sleep(5)
        print("Pasajero", id, "bajando del ascensor. Piso:", pisoActual)
        listaDestino.pop(0)
    
        mutex.release()
        multiplex.release()

def subirPersona():
    #Funcion en la que el elevador sube o baja hasta el piso al que lo llamaron
    
def bajarPersona():
    #Funcion en la que el elevador sube o baja hasta el piso el piso destino del usuario
    
Thread(target=ascensor).start()
for i in range(max_pasajeros):
    Thread(target=pasajero, args=[i]).start()
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que únicamente sube una persona al elevador a la vez, en otras palabras, un usuario lo usa y una vez que baja otra persona lo usa.
Tengo entendido que **multiplex** permite que el límite de 5 personas puedan usarlo al mismo tiempo. Incluso ya lo quité y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. ¿Alguna idea de lo que está ocurriendo?

Comment: No necesitas threads para la simulación.

Comment: Te sería útil obtener un valor random entre 0-5, que te dice cuantas personas suben/bajan en un piso determinado. Luego ciclas agregando tal cantidad de personas al ascensor.

Comment: Creo que deberías enfocarte en el ascensor como sujeto de la simulación. Los pasajeros son idénticos y sólo necesitas saber cuantos hay en el ascensor y en cada piso.